# Code works in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

This code works perfectly with Firefox but not with  Chrome.

I'm using a webserver with chrome so the `.load()` works fine.

```
$(function(){
  $("#header").load("header.html"); 
});


$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#notif').text("5");
}
```

When I debug using chrome, the code executes fine but nothing is inserted in `<span id="notif"></span>`.

The `<span id="notif"></span>` that is in my `header.html` is loaded dynamically with JS.

Again, it works fine in firefox but not in Chrome.

Comment: Can you post a link to your page?

Comment: the load method of jquery is asynchronous. So I think that the load is not finished when the document ready is fired.

Comment: Is `list_notif` included on page load, or by XHR (AJAX) after/during page load? If by XHR, are there any network errors?

Comment: Why not use the complete parameter in the load function

Comment: @Bee157 I think you're right, how can  I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the load is asynchronous, so the document will be ready (and have triggered) well before the end of the load.
In short $('#notif') does not exist when document is ready, because it is not loaded yet.

```
 $(function(){
   $("#header").load("header.html",function(){
     $('#notif').text('5');
   }); 
 });
```

not the second parameter, the anonymous function, will start after the successful completion of the load.

the difference between firefox and chrome can be related to the speed of downloading, but I'm not 100% sure. More testing is needed.

> sometimes (especially IE) debugging the code via a breakpoint, may cause enough delay to the document.ready trigger to have finished loading. So no "faults" are discovered.